# On epsilon delta definition fo Limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Is it possible to use $\delta=\min(1,\frac\varepsilon c)$ in the following exercise? Thanks in advance!!

$$\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2+4x)=5.$$

To make my question clear, do we have a right to choose the limit constant a as $\delta$?

Comment: You can do that (if $c>0$), but the important question is: why?

Comment: @John: I guess the OP tries to find $\delta$ which assures that the distance to the limit is less than $\epsilon$. In such case I would expect $\delta$ to be related to $\sqrt\epsilon$. To the OP: have you tried making a full square there, that is showing that $\lim_{x\to 1}(x+2)^2 = 9$?

Comment: Not really: ($x^2 -1 = (x-1)(x+1)$). @Ilya Anyway the OP needs to tell us the strategy, so that we can give suitable advices.

Answer (score 1):

For any $ \epsilon >0$, let $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{7}\}$. Then when $|x-1| < \delta$, clearly, $|x+5|=|x-1+6|<|x-1|+6 \le 7$, and hence

$$|x^2+4x-5|=|(x+5)| \times |(x-1)| \le 7\delta \le \epsilon.$$