# Proof of Epsilon - Delta Limit

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to prove the limit of the following:

$\lim x \rightarrow 1 $ of  $x^2+2x$ where the limit $L = 3$

This gives us $0<|x-1|<\delta$ and $|x^2+2x-3|<\epsilon$

First I factorize $f(x) \rightarrow$ $|(x+3)(x-1)|<\epsilon$

$\rightarrow |x+3||x-1|<\epsilon $

I recognize that I get a matching term $|x-1|$, however I have an uncontrolled term $|x+3|$.

$|x-1|<\epsilon/|x+3| $

If I assume $|x-1|<\delta$ and $\delta < 1$

Edit, made some progress;

I.e. making a restriction that $x$ can be a maximum distance of 1 away from $a$.

$|x-1| < 1$

$0< x<2$

$3<x+3<5$

Thus, $\epsilon/|x+3|$ is at its minimum when $|x+3|$ is at its maximum

$|x-1|< \frac\epsilon5$

Comment: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~yosenl/math/epsilon-delta.pdf provides examples that you may want to see

Comment: Good stuff, thanks @NickLiu, I was looking for some examples like this.

Comment: Slightly similar question: [Showing that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(x^2+4x)=5$ using an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049665/201168).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* You can add a condition depending on the size of $\epsilon$. i.e change your $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon$. What happens if you let

$$\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\}?$$

If $|x-1| < \delta$ then what do you know about $|x+3|$ and $|x-1|$ in terms of constants and $\epsilon$?

**Edit:** Here is a full solution at the OPs request.

Let $f(x) = x^2 +2x$. Given $\epsilon > 0$ define $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\}$. 
We note that

\begin{align*}
|f(x) -1| &= |x^2 + 2x -3|\\
&=|x+3||x-1|.
\end{align*}
When $|x-1| < \delta$ we have $|x-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$ and $|x+3| <5$ and hence

\begin{align*}
|f(x)-1|&=|x+3||x-1|\\
&\le 5 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{5}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}

We have shown that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{5}\}$ such that when $|x-1|<\delta$, $|f(x) -1| < \epsilon$. This implies that $f(x) \rightarrow 1$ when $x \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Well then; $0<|x-1|<\epsilon/5$ and $|x+3| |x-1| < \epsilon$ which means that it is greater by a factor of 5. Thus, $5|x-1|<\epsilon$

$\rightarrow |x+3||x-1|<\epsilon$

$\rightarrow |x+3|<5$

$\rightarrow x<2$

Not sure if I'm getting anywhere, but I'll read through the PDF posted by @NickLiu

Comment: Good thinking - $|x-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$ if $|x-1|< \delta$. Notice also that $|x+3| <5$ when $|x-1|< \delta$. Overall this implies $|x-1||x+3|<5 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{5} = \epsilon$ when $|x-1|<\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my original post

$|x-1|<\epsilon/|x+3|<\frac\epsilon5$

We have two restrictions:

1) $|x-1|<1$

2) $|x-1|<\frac\epsilon5$

Let $\delta=$ min{$1,\frac\epsilon5$}

Proof:

Given a $\epsilon>0$, and  let $\delta =\frac\epsilon5$

We know that $3<x+3<5$, thus:

$|x-1|<\frac\epsilon5$

$\rightarrow |x-1|(x+3)<\frac\epsilon5(5)$ **(*)**

$\rightarrow |x^2+2x-3|<\epsilon$

$\rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

**(*)** This part makes sense, however I am not 100 % sure why we do it. I just got it from another example. Why do we multiply by x+3 and 5 (different values)? I know that $x+3 < 5$ but still...

Now let $\delta=1$ (BTW is it common to prove for both delta values?

$|x-1|<1$

$|x-1|(x+3)<(x+3)$ here we multiply by the same quantity for some reason...

$|x^2+2x-3|<x+3<5<\epsilon$

$|x^2+2x-3|<\epsilon$

And I think that's it. This is my first encounter with proofs actually, so I'm still a noob. All tips are welcome.

Comment: Great to see you answer your own question! +1

Comment: The way you've written your answer is confusing - why have you written $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5}$  in the line under 'Proof'? The line after this one (the one about $x+3$ being bounded) does not follow with such $\delta$.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but as I understand it, you are supposed to prove for different values of $\delta$? Let me re-write it; I added a "let", does that make more sense?

Comment: The idea is to find **one** $\delta$ that works for a given $\epsilon$. What my answer is trying to say, is that your $\delta$ may be different for different $\epsilon$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. The $\delta-\epsilon$ definition shows that for any given $\delta$, I can provide you with a matching $\epsilon$, right? But I don't understand what I would change about my proof.

Edit: So you are saying I should eliminate the part where delta = 1? Since delta should be one specific value?

Comment: You seem to be swapping $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. You want to find $\delta$ given $\epsilon$ so that if $|x-1| < \delta$ then $|x-1||x+3| < \epsilon$ - at least that's the way that's implied in your question.

Comment: Would you like me to write out a full answer?

Comment: I've added it in to my answer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. And thanks for the full answer.